# Differentiate between 13 inches and >20 inches screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to have different layout for different screens.

I want <= 20 screens to looks different than > 20 screens. But bootstrap seems to work with both same (as **col-lg-xx**).

Any they any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is based on screen resolution, not actual screen size. So no, there isn't really any way to do what you're asking. If you want to shoot for resolution, and you want to do something different than what vanilla Bootstrap is doing, you can write your own media queries.